# Java 8 Memory allocation

Tags: java, jar, out-of-memory, heap-memory, java-memory-model

Let's assume that I have JDK/JRE 8 also I've added JAVA_OPTS= -Xmx8G -Xms1G.

I've stated without any other params (java -jar 1.jar; java -jar 2.jar) 2 simple jars. So now I have two java process.

1) Do they executed in one JVM (as two java process) or each process will be executed in separated JVM?

2) -Xmx8G -Xms1G heap size will be applied to **separately** each of two executed jars or this heap size will be something common for two executed jars?

3) What will be with memory allocation if start one jar ( java -jar 1.jar) 
and another with java -jar 2.jar Xmx12G?

P.S. Would we nice if you have any good links.

P.S.S Don't Ask what I'm smoking :)

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: With visual vm, but its not very clear for me for now

Comment: Try `ps` or Task Manager.

Comment: Side note - it's P.P.S., not P.S.S.

Comment: according to `ps` each jar running in separated JVM.  JAVA_OPTS applied to each JVM

Comment: There you go, that's your answer

Comment: @Korashen so Im correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to analyze JVM instances in your system. Just open JMC(Java Mission Control). Whenever you execute any application it will show as an individual jvm there. ex : if you run jar1 and jar2 the JMC will show three JVMs- jar1, jar2 ,jmc. Then, you can use use MBean Browser there to analyze your all jvm.

Hope it helps.